# How to compare the IDs of edge classes for truthiness with a many-to-many join table

Tags: ruby, sinatra, join

I am working in Sinatra on a project, and have the following domain:

```
User-< User_car >-Car
```

Within the `User_cars` table I have the foreign key IDs of the `User_ID` and the `Car_ID`.

The issue I'm having is:

```
patch '/cars/:id' do 
    @cars = Car.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if current_user.id == user_cars.user_id
      @cars.update
      redirect to "/cars"
    else
      erb :"/cars/index"
    end
  end
```

Also there is the helper method for `current_user` in `ApplicationController`:

```
def current_user
      # returns the current_user object if there is one, otherwise nil
      # checks the session hash and finds a user based on the :user_id key
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

I cannot edit as it stands because I don't have a way to evaluate the `current_user` as the "owner"/creator of the car with the IDs as they will never evaluate to truthy.  I am not even getting an error, I just get forwarded to the `/cars/index` page.